# What is the difference between in-built log2(x) function and iterative dividing by 2?

Tags: c++, exponential

I have to compute log2() of an integer or long long integer. Why these two methods give different results?

I have tried taking out log2() by in-built function in c++, which is resulting into wrong answers for long long integer. But by iterative division by 2 and counting the iteration, the answer is coming out to be right.

Use of log2(x) :

```
long long int n;
cin >> n;
double store= log2(n);
long long int y = (long long int) store;
```

Use of iteration :

```
long long int n;
cin >> n;
int f=-1;
long long int k=n;
while(k>0)
{
    k/=2;
    f++;
}
```

The answers for long long integer is showing to be wrong by in-built function method.

Comment: `log` operates on floating point numbers, and floating point numbers are imprecise. Many things can go wrong when the result is truncated back to an integer.

Comment: if `n` is of kind `2^k` then both methods should converge. If not, `k/2` get rounded to an integer, and this way gets wrong.

Comment: @Ripi2 Mathematically, index of highest bit of value n is equal to floor(log2(n)). So the rounding gets only a problem if you are after the decimal places, which apparently is not the case...

Comment: @Aconcagua I don't get your explanation. Can you show the flow with `n=7`?

Comment: @user4581301Actually, stuff can go wrong already in opposite direction, double has less precision (54 bit, only 53 for denormalised numbers), long long at least 63 (if considering MSB as sign bit that double has as well). The rest of the bits of double is 'wasted' for the mantissa...

Comment: @Ripi2 log2(8) == 3, log2(4) == 2, log2(7) is just a bit less than 2,81. Divisions by 2 will result in 7 -> 3 -> 1 -> 0, which are 3 divisions. We always have one division 'too much' (that's why question author started with -1), so result is 2. Just the same as we would get with 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0...

Comment: @Aconcagua Got it. Thanks.